# Sudden Closed Connection Exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jboss, redhat

My source code works fine in WebSphere, but when its migrated to JBoss server, I am getting such error. 
Using warfiles for deployment and Oracle as database.
I hope someone could shed some light.

I have already searched possible answers and scenarios but I'm getting no luck.
I was getting error at this line, in conn.

```
conn = setDBConnection();
cstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
```

Here is the sample log.

```
10:40:27,576 [Outside DIR] WARN  [listener.TxConnectionListener] - IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@3e447f64[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@7eed4af connection handles=1 lastReturned=1557196808308 lastValidated=1557196802534 lastCheckedOut=1557196827576 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@3ffa012 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@46fd2e09[pool=CRM] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@69d31ab0[connectionListener=3e447f64 connectionManager=16b60ec2 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options jndiName=java:jboss/jdbc/CRM] txSync=null]
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareCall(PhysicalConnection.java:3204)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareCall(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:820)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareCall(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:806)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareCall(WrappedConnection.java:661)
        at ph.com.crm.modules.catalog.access.CatalogAccess.getPlanHandset(CatalogAccess.java:525)
        at ph.com.crm.modules.catalog.ajax.ProductCatalogAjaxHandlerProcessor.getPlanHandsets(ProductCatalogAjaxHandlerProcessor.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
        at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
        at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
        at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
        at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

UPDATE:
I added try-catch to surround the line

```
conn = setDBConnection();
            logger.debug("Inside here:"+conn);

            try {
                logger.debug("TRYING:");
                cstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                logger.debug("####### CATCHING");
                logger.debug("CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
                logger.debug("NEXT EXCEPTION "+e.getNextException());
                logger.debug("SQL STATE: "+e.getSQLState());
                logger.debug("ERROR CODE: "+e.getErrorCode());



            }
```

console result:

```
:44:08,123 [Outside DIR] DEBUG [access.CatalogAccess] - ####### CATCHING
12:44:08,123 [Outside DIR] DEBUG [access.CatalogAccess] - CAUSE: null
12:44:08,124 [Outside DIR] DEBUG [access.CatalogAccess] - NEXT EXCEPTION null
12:44:08,124 [Outside DIR] DEBUG [access.CatalogAccess] - SQL STATE: 99999
12:44:08,125 [Outside DIR] DEBUG [access.CatalogAccess] - ERROR CODE: 17008

``
```

Comment: Did you configure JBoss server with a validation query, so stale connections in the connection pool are detected and refreshed?

Comment: I will check that. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Under datasource configuration in JBOSS, set Validate On Match as 'true'

Comment: You should click the check mark to accept this answer, so others can see your question has been answered.